# How to compare values with each other(no repeat) within a list in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey I want to compare each value in a list with each other and I don't want the same value to compare twice, for example, ab  = ba also 'a' does not need to compare with 'a' itself

```
list = [a,b,c,d,e]
```

output:

```
#### not necessarily in this format
ab bc cd
ac bd ce
ad be
ae
```

Comment: try to show some code...

Comment: You want `itertools.combinations`. Look it up in the docs; if you can’t figure out how to use it, post your attempt and where you’re stuck.

Answer (score 3):

For this you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
from itertools import combinations

for i in combinations([1,2,3,4], 2):
  print(i)
```

This prints:

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 loops one inside the other, where the inner loop always starts from the next index the outer loop currently has

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]

outer_index = 0
while(outer_index < len(l)):
    inner_index = outer_index+1
    while(inner_index < len(l)):
        print(str(l[outer_index]) + ", " +  str(l[inner_index]))
        inner_index = inner_index+1
    outer_index = outer_index+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question. 
This is my approach without using libraries, just simple code:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
e=5

list = [a,b,c,d,e]
for index, i in enumerate(list):
    list2=list[index+1:]
    for j in list2:
        print i, j
```

Output:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 3
2 4
2 5
3 4
3 5
4 5
```

Instead of 'print', you can use your function to compare the variables

For sure, the code can be optimized (more pythonic), but this is one approach

Comment: Sorry Saketh Katari, we had same idea